# Gitlab - set project to be visible to users who don't have an account on gitlab

Tags: gitlab

We have a scenario where we have a "**public**" project in gitlab.

We need to be able to make this "**public**" project accessible (browse only access) to **anyone** that can reach the link we provide them with.

Also, we don't want them to have an actual account on our gitlab instance.
I'm guessing that we may be able to make use of a `guest` account, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Any assistance / guidance / pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitlab allows you to set your Project visibility to [public](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html#public-projects) which allows unauthenticated users to view the project at the **/public** URL.